# If $b-a≥1$, then there exist at least one positive integer in $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a,b)$ be a real interval such that $0<a<b$.

My question is this claim is true: If $b-a≥1$, then there exist at least one positive integer in the interval $(a,b)$. If no, so, what is the conditions for that.

Comment: Try a contrapositive approach

Comment: It's not true.  Let $a=1$, $b=2$.

Comment: If you meant the closed interval $[a,b]$, say, then, Hint:  let $n=\lfloor a \rfloor$ and argue that $a<n+1≤b$.  This also works if you meant to assume that $b-a>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is not an integer then let's take $n=\lfloor a\rfloor+1$.

By definition of floor function we have $n\le a+1\lt n+1$ and since $a$ not an integer the inequality on the left is strict $n\lt a+1\lt n+1$

$b-a\ge 1\iff a+1\le b$ so $n<b$ and $n\in]a,b[$.

If $a$ is an integer then $n=a\notin]a,b[$

Now if $n=a+1$

- if $b-a<1\iff a+1>b$ then $n>b$ and $n\notin]a,b[$
- if $b-a=1\iff a+1=b$ then $n=b$ and $n\notin]a,b[$
- if $b-a>1\iff a+1<b$ then $n<b$ and $n\in]a,b[$

Answer (score 2):

If $b-a \geq 1$ then there is not necessarily some integer $k \geq 1$ such that $a < k < b$. For instance, if $a=2$ and $b = 3$, then $b-a = 1$ and there is no integer between $2$ and $3$; if $a =2.1$ and $b=3.1$ then $k = 3$ is such that $a < k < b$.

However, if $b-a>1$ then there is some integer $k \geq 1$ such that $a < k < b$; for otherwise there is some pair of consecutive integers whose difference is $>1$.